# rails strong parameter error on array attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, active-model-serializers

i try to post my json to rails server with this request body

```
    {"post":{
    "user_id": 2,
    "title": "kehangatan di pagi hari",
    "category": "kehangatan di pagi hari",
    "imageposts": [{"imageurl":"DJAWHDAHWDKJHAW DHJAWDHAWDAWDAD"}],
    "description":"<p>memang sange</p>"
  } }
```

and this is my posts_params

```
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :user_id, :description, :category, :imageposts => [:imageurl])
  end
```

unfortunately when i make an ajax post i got an error in my terminal

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Imagepost(#42287660) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#30074960)>
```

i've trying this to my imageposts strong parameter but it doesnt work too

```
imageposts: [:imageurl]
```

can anybody solve this...

Comment: Post the received `params` (See server log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strong params` are fine. The problem is that `imageposts` is an association, but, just a guess, it is tried to be set as an attribute `post.update_attributes(post_params)`

If you want it to be updated like this, the possible solution is to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

Your model must have something like:

```
class Post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :imageposts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :imageposts
end
```

And the name of params must be `imageposts_attributes` instead of just `imageposts`:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :user_id, :description, :category, :imageposts_attributes => [:imageurl])
end
```

Comment: its work but it replied    => {
    "imageposts.post": [
        "must exist"
    ]
}. while i has a post_id attributes

Comment: Hm, please, try `has_many :imageposts, inverse_of: :post` in the Post model. Let's see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You are passing multiple images. So you can use `coocoon gem` with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

for more info https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon